# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.mycompany.myapp2. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:240)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.mycompany.myapp2.VerifyPhoneActivity.onCreate(VerifyPhoneActivity.java:39)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)
01-06 20:22:35.822 17166 17166 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 9 more

public class VerifyPhoneActivity extends Activity {

```
private String verificationId;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(VerifyPhoneActivity.this);
    setContentView(R.layout.phone);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);

    String phonenumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phonenumber");
    sendVerificationCode(phonenumber);

    findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {

                    editText.setError("Enter code...");
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        });

}

private void verifyCode(String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithCredential(credential);
}

private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
}

private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        number,
        60,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
        mCallBack
    );

}

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        verificationId = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            editText.setText(code);
            verifyCode(code);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

}

Comment: If you can't figure out what your own stack trace means, what makes you think that anyone this site would be able to?  Please include the relevant Java code which you think is causing this exception, and then highlight at what we should be looking.

Comment: Added code please see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.mycompany.myapp2. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Before you call

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```